# Raspberry Pi Google Assistant Issues

Tags: python, google-api, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence, google-assistant-sdk

I followed [this](https://becominghuman.ai/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-homemade-google-home-9e29ad220075) tutorial recently and have had an issue. I can't seem to get it working but when i run the command `sudo /home/pi/google-assistant-init.sh` to start it, I get this error:

```
/home/pi/main.py:16: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/main.py", line 52, in main
    with Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'device_model_id'
```

and I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be appreciated. I have completed all the steps too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is old. Since then, developers have had to [register a device model](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device) before running the script. After registering it the first time you'll be able to run the project without issue.

Comment: What device type do I use at the first screen

Comment: Any device type would work. `LIGHT` is a pretty generic choice. The device type is primarily used as metadata and does not affect the functionality of the device.